# io is not defined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, socket.io

My io is undefined, what are possible reasons for this?

arduino.js

```
var debug = require('debug')('arduino');
var five = require('johnny-five');
var socket = io();
```

index.js

```
var debug = require('debug')('server');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var socketIo = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIo(httpServer);
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: What is the relationship between arduino.js and index.js?

Answer (score 3):

`io` is a local variable in the `index.js` module.

`arduino.js` is a different module.

It doesn't appear to use `index.js`, nor does `index.js` appear to use it. Even if that was the case, `io` is a local variable that isn't exported so is not available outside the module it is defined in.

Comment: how do i define io() so its the same one in both modules and the events listen to each other

Comment: Someone more familiar with Socket.io may have a better answer, but if you want to pass the `io` variable between modules you could do this: In `index.js`: `exports.io = io;`, then in `arduino.js`: `const io = require('index').io;`.